# select column in data frame based on NAs in rows

Tags: r, hierarchy, na

Say I have a data frame of 7 columns, with some rows having 7 values and others with NAs past a certain point. I want to grab the last value (going left to right) that is not NA and then the value directly to the left. It is hierarchical data, but some groups go deeper than others. I want the deepest and the second deepest groups in two columns in a new data frame.

This code works but maxes out my memory for a data frame of 46K observations. Is there a more efficient way I'm not thinking of?

```
df <- data.frame(LEVEL1 = c('animal', 'vegetable', 'mineral'),
                 LEVEL2 = c('mammal', 'pepper', 'rock'),
                 LEVEL3 = c('dog', 'jalepeno', NA),
                 LEVEL4 = c('westie', NA, NA))

deepest <- apply(df, 1, 
                  function(x) length(which(!is.na(x))))
one.up <- apply(df, 1, 
                    function(x) length(which(!is.na(x)))-1)
len <- nrow(df)
output <- data.frame(one.up = unlist(sapply(1:len, 
                            function(x) df[x, one.up[x]])),
                     deepest= unlist(sapply(1:len, 
                                            function(x) df[x, deepest[x]])))
```

First time posting. Usually I can cobble together what I need from this site. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could save running that loop twice with a simple `apply` call, like:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) {
+     n <- max(which(!is.na(x)))
+     x[(n-1):n]
+ })
     [,1]     [,2]       [,3]     
[1,] "dog"    "pepper"   "mineral"
[2,] "westie" "jalepeno" "rock"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure your code would deliver what you think it ought if the NAs might be interspersed through the lengths of the rows (although you say this should not happen.) This code will stop before the first NA and return the two prior values.

```
> output.m <- apply(df,1,function(x) { leng.na <-rle(is.na(x))$lengths[1]
                                       tail(x[1:leng.na],2) }  )
> output.d <- as.data.frame(t(output.m))
> output.d
       V1       V2
1     dog   westie
2  pepper jalepeno
3 mineral     rock
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'm pretty sure my data has no 'inner' NAs, but I didn't know about the rle function. That'll come in handy.